# Pandas Dataframe: group by year and month

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, counter, series

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of 'date_created'

the column has a following format of YYYY-MM-DD. for example: 2017-10-05

I want to group it by MM/YYYY

I used this but it included DD

```
frame['date_created'].value_counts()
```

is there anyway to query it by using YYYY and MM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would create a new column, say "YearMonth" with day fixed to 1. Then group by this column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2017-10-05', '2017-10-20']})
df['YearMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).map(lambda dt: dt.replace(day=1))

res = df['YearMonth'].value_counts()

# 2017-10-01    2
# Name: YearMonth, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also group by month and `count` over

```
frame.set_index("date_created").groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).count()
```